# Calling Functions from another Environment

Tags: r

I seem to be having trouble with function environments today. I have a bunch of objects, many of which are functions which call each other, saved to my drive as an `.RData` file:

```
irrelevant_var <- 123
fun1 <- function(x) x+fun2(x)
fun2 <- function(x) x^2
save(irrelevant_var, fun1, fun2, file = "myEnv.RData")
rm(irrelevant_var, fun1, fun2)
```

I then load those objects into a new environment:

```
myEnv <- new.env()
load("myEnv.RData", envir = myEnv)
```

I then create a new meta function to work with the objects in `myEnv`.

```
meta_fun <- function(x) fun1(x)
meta_fun(1)
Error in meta_fun(1) : could not find function "fun1"
```

Calling `meta_fun` now won't work, because `fun1` is in another environment, so I do this:

```
environment(meta_fun) <- myEnv
```

Now, I'm expecting a call to `meta_fun` to work, and it finds `fun1` but now cannot find `fun2`.

```
meta_fun(1)
Error in fun1(x) : could not find function "fun2"
```

How can I get `meta_fun` to work? Also, it isn't know beforehand how many functions are in `myEnv` or how nested they are.

Comment: Wait, why did you `rm` `fun1` and `fun2`? Also, [a useful reference](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html).

Comment: I removed them because I wanted a clean example of the construction of `myEnv` in this post. In reality, I might have been handed myEnv.RData from on high and not know where it comes from.

Comment: simplest way would probably be to `attach(myEnv)` before the call

Comment: That works, but my understanding is that `attach(myEnv)` creates a copy of all the objects in `myEnv` and puts them into a new environment on the search path. Is there a way to put `myEnv` on the search path directly without creating a copy?

Comment: Looks like you can attach directly from a file, avoiding a copy: `attach("myEnv.RData")`. But what if this isn't an option?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would strongly encourage you to rethink your strategy. Trying to run code in specific environments (not attached to the search path) really isn't that fun.

Now, the problem is really with the environments of `fun1` and `fun2`. You define them in the global environment in this example so that's reflected in the `environment()` properties of the function (functions capture the environment where they are defined). That means that despite the fact that the name `fun1` lives in the `myEnv` environment, that function has it's environment point to global, not `myEnv` (it doesn't change because it's being reloaded, not redefined). Thus it cannot resolve the `fun2` symbol. See:

```
environment(myEnv$fun1)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

If you wanted to build those functions inside the environment, the a better way would be

```
myEnv <- new.env()
evalq({
    fun1 <- function(x) x+fun2(x)
    fun2 <- function(x) x^2
}, myEnv)
```

now check out the environment

```
environment(myEnv$fun1)
# <environment: 0x7ff507b31860>
myEnv
# <environment: 0x7ff507b31860>
```

Then you can either 1) define your meta_fun in the same environment

```
evalq(meta_fun <- function(x) fun1(x), myEnv)
meta_fun(4)
# [1] 20
```

or 2) change the environment of the `meta_fun` as you did before

```
meta_fun <- function(x) fun1(x)
environment(meta_fun) <- myEnv
meta_fun(4)
# [1] 20
```

Also, i'm pretty sure `attach()` doesn't make copies of objects unless you attempt to write to them. If you have a different reference for that, i'd be interested to see it.

Comment: The `?attach` documentation led me to think copies were being made. Specifically, this part of the Details: "The database is not actually attached. Rather, a new environment is created on the search path and the elements of a list (including columns of a data frame) or objects in a save file or an environment are copied into the new environment"

Comment: Unfortunately, these environments are out of my control, so I'm hard-pressed to think of another strategy. Based on what you said, though, I'm going to explore the possibility of looping or `apply`ing through `myEnv`, detecting function objects, and setting their environment to `myEnv`.

Comment: How are these environments out of your control? How have you gotten into this situation in the first place? Seems like it would be better to address the real problem rather than come up with a messy clean up procedure.

Comment: `myEnv` is an output from an upstream process. It would be great if all software could be developed with a holistic approach, but sadly, I've found this to rarely be the case in my industry.

Comment: Using `pryr`, it appears that a deep copy is not being made. `myenv<-new.env(); assign("a", function(x) x+2, envir=myenv); b<-myenv$a; pryr::address(b); attach(myenv); pryr::address(a)`. Both the attached version of the function and the version in the env have the same memory address.

Comment: In that case, I think `attach` is the answer.